# Laravel file master, routing and two of the same file path

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Hello maybe it's stupid question, but I don't know how I can pass the `variable` to the `master.blade.php` file. For example I have file master.blade.php and article.blade.php, and file controller: `MastersController` and `ArticlesController`. In file `ArticlesController` I have method `index`:

```
public function index(){
    $variable = 'Hello!';
    return view('master', compact('variable');
}
```

In file `article.blade.php` I have:

```
@extends('master')
@section('content')
   {{ $variable }}
@stop
```

And file routing I have:

```
Route::resource('/', 'ArticlesController');
```

Now I have second method in file `MastersController`:

```
public function master(){
    $master= 'Hello Master';
    return view('master', compact('master');
}
```

And in file `master.blade.php` I have:

```
{{ $master }}
```

And here comes the problem, because the variable `$master` was transferred to a file `master.blade.php` have to add the path to the file in the `class routing`, so my file `web.php` (routing class in Laravel 5.3) I have:

```
Route::resource('/', 'ArticlesController');
Route::get('/', 'MastersController@master');
```

I know it's not good, but I don't know how I can write routing with  two of the same file path.

***EDIT:***

file `master.blade.php` is added to more file, which have other route, for example: `www.mypage.com/sport/1/real-madrid` or `www.mypage.com/contact` ... And in this case, the script is not working properly.

Comment: I don't think I quite get what you are saying. You have two `routes` which points to separate methods in separate `controllers`. And both the `controllers` pass different variables to the same `blade` file. So what is the question.

Comment: @Gayan beacuse file master.blade.php is added to more file, which have other route, for example: www.mypage.com/sport/1/real-madrid or www.mypage.com/contact ... And in this case, the script is not working properly